# Geospatial data of Adventureworks database

Tags: geospatial, spatial, qliksense

I am new to Qliksense and I am practicing app (dashboard) development concepts on MS SQL Server's Adventureworks database. In one specific table, the Address table, there is a column which has Spatial Location data. The data is in the following format, Dallas - 0xE6100000010C10A810D1886240403A0F0653663158C0. The data is of the geography datatype and is said to represent latitude and longitude information of given address. I am trying to create a map and a GeoKey as a dimension, but GeoMakePoint() function takes latitude and longitude as a tuple and not in this format. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution myself. Just use the method [Columnname].Lat and [Columnname].Long on the geography datatype to extract the Latitude and Longitude values from column values. Store these values in separate columns during data load and use them as GeoKey.